# Why OpenGL X and Z axis got inverted sometimes?

Tags: opengl, glfw

I'm having some troubles with my game code. I'm developing a **Voxel Engine** and everything is fine, but sometimes (like 30% of times) when I build and run my project, the X and Z axis got inverted (I know it because the model position and Camera motion), and I dont know why this is hapenning.

May this is a bug on my graphic card, or my code is broken is some place? If so, any clue where to start looking for?

Here are two pics to show what i'm saying, I didnt made any change in code, just compiled twice and got it like this:

[image: Normal Axis]
[image: Inverted Axis (Problem)]

Here are my settings:

**Compiler:** VS 2013 Express
**PC:** Dell Inspiron R14
**SO:** Windows 8
**Graphics Card:** NVIDIA GT 630M and Intel HD Graphics 4000
**Libs:** GLFW 3.0.4, GLEW 1.10, GLM 0.9.5.2
**OpenGL Context:** 4.0

Comment: You sure you're not just multiplying your matrixes wrong ? Or simply multiplying with a negative number?

Comment: Not a chance is it because your computer configuration. I suggest deploy breakpoints and move slowly through the initialization (obviously not for every cube, just a few of them).

Comment: @Sidar, if so, why sometimes (with no change on code) it works fine?

Comment: I am 100% it's a bug in your math library, or using it.

Comment: @JánosTuránszki, thanks for the tip, I'll check anyway. But again, the strange thing is it works fine sometimes (with no code change).

Comment: @AfonsoLage you probably have a subtle branching error. Or remember that the zero is actually signed, so might be causing you some trouble, flipping the sign in some occasions.

Comment: @concept3d, Do you know a good Math Library to test? I'm using GLM because it's very handy.

Comment: I am using glm too in my projects, and it's fine, try using Eigen? but it's not as easy as GLM.

Comment: @concept3d, you may right. If I got some value untialized and it's negative, it'll cause a misbehavior. I'll check for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the main problem. My Camera rotation didnt got an yAxis clamp, so when I build my project and click on it, the mouse position was different and sometimes made the yAxis be 180 or -180, which caused the issue.

A simple clamp solved it:

```
yAxis = glm::clamp(yAxis, -90.0f, 90.0f);
```

Thanks for those who help me out!